# Hangman if Statement Issue

Tags: perl

I can't seem to find why my Perl Hangman code:

```
#!\usr\bin\perl
use 5.016;
&hangman;
sub hangman{
    our(@graphics,@words,$word,@chars,$hidden,$incorrect,$guess,);
    @graphics=("=========",
    "        |\n        |\n        |\n        |\n        |\n=========",
    "   ======\n        |\n        |\n        |\n        |\n        |\n=========",
    "   ======\n   |    |\n        |\n        |\n        |\n        |\n=========",
    "   ======\n   |    |\n   O    |\n        |\n        |\n        |\n=========",
    "   ======\n   |    |\n   O    |\n   |    |\n        |\n        |\n=========",
    "   ======\n   |    |\n   O    |\n  /|    |\n        |\n        |\n=========",
    "   ======\n   |    |\n   O    |\n  /|\\   |\n        |\n        |\n=========",
    "   ======\n   |    |\n   O    |\n  /|\\   |\n  /     |\n        |\n=========",
    "   ======\n   |    |\n   O    |\n  /|\\   |\n  / \\   |\n        |\n=========");
    @words=qw(ant baboon badger bat bear beaver camel cat clam cobra cougar coyote crow deer dog donkey duck eagle ferret fox frog goat goose hawk lion lizard llama mole monkey moose mouse mule newt otter owl panda parrot pigeon python rabbit ram rat raven rhino salmon seal shark sheep skunk sloth snake spider stork swan tiger toad trout turkey turtle weasel whale wolf wombat zebra);
    $word=$words[rand scalar@words];
    for(0..length$word){
        @chars=split("",$word);
    }
    $hidden="-"x length($word);
    while($incorrect<0+@graphics){
        print"Word: $hidden\nGuess a letter: ";
        chomp($guess=<STDIN>);
        foreach(@chars){
            if($guess==$_){
                    substr($hidden,$_)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Always runs the `if` statement on line 25. I'm trying to create an `if` statement so that it only runs if `guess` is in `word`
Anyone have any information as to why this is happening and how I can stop it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it to:

```
if ($guess eq $_)
```

In perl, `==` is for numbers, `eq` is for strings. If you give strings to `==`, it converts them to numbers, and they convert to `0`.

You should enable warnings, then it would have warned you that this was happening.

There's also a problem with the next line:

```
$chars[$_]=$guess;
```

Array indexes must be positive integers, but `$_` is a string (the correctly guessed character). I'm not sure what you're trying to do here -- you should be displaying the match to the user.

Answer (score -1):

As you've said in your Question

> I'm trying to create an if statement so that it only runs if ***guess is***
>   ***in word***,

you should check with regexp.

So, your `if` condition should be

```
if($_ =~ /\Q$guess\E/i)
```

Comment: Not a good solution. **(1)** `$_ =~ /pattern/` is equivalent to the shorter `/pattern/`. **(2)** *Never* interpolate unchecked user input into regexes. Regexes can contain code. Regexes can produce segfaults. Also, an always matching pattern (like `.?`) could game the system. To protect against metacharacters, enclose the interpolation by `\Q...\E`. You don't even anchor the regex at the start and the end of string, so it is fairly useless. **(3)** To test for case-insensitive equality, do `lc($_) eq lc($guess)`.